# Running an external python controller from console

Tags: webots

While trying to figure out how to integrate the gym interface, I'm trying to get an extern robot python controller running from console.
I have follwed the offical [guide](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/running-extern-robot-controllers?tab-os=macos&tab-language=python) and my (macOS) env vars set accordingly.

When I try to run the controller by typing:

```
python (path to controller.py)
```

I get the following message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'controller'
```

Can someone give me a tip how to figure this out?

==========

Update: As asked in the comments, here's my output

```
environ({'TERM_PROGRAM': 'Hyper', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TMPDIR': '/var/folders/g1/sqrwrg2d5mn9d48z24mng2280000gn/T/', 'CONDA_SHLVL': '1', 'CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER': '(base) ', 'TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION': '3.0.2', 'WEBOTS_HOME': '/Applications/Webots', 'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'UTF-8', 'USER': '[user]', 'CONDA_EXE': '/Users/[user]/anaconda3/bin/conda', '__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING': '0x1F5:0x0:0x0', '_CE_CONDA': '', 'PATH': '/Users/[user]/anaconda3/bin:/Users/[user]/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands', 'CONDA_PREFIX': '/Users/[user]/anaconda3', 'PWD': '/Users/[user]', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'XPC_FLAGS': '0x0', '_CE_M': '', 'XPC_SERVICE_NAME': '0', 'SHLVL': '1', 'HOME': '/Users/[user]', 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/Applications/Webots/lib/controller:', 'PYTHONPATH': '/Applications/Webots/lib/controller/python3X:', 'CONDA_PYTHON_EXE': '/Users/[user]/anaconda3/bin/python', 'LOGNAME': '[user]', 'CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV': 'base', 'COLORTERM': 'truecolor', '_': '/Users/[user]/anaconda3/bin/python'})
```

Python version

```
print(sys.version)
3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
```

==========

**Update 2**: Segmentation fault: 11 error

Here is my crash report / macOS console output when trying to run "python [extern robot controller].py"

[image: Log from console app]

Full Crash Report:

```
Process:               python3.7 [6940]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/python3.7
Identifier:            python3.7
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [5209]
Responsible:           python3.7 [6940]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-01-22 11:34:43.349 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G2022)
Report Version:        12

Time Awake Since Boot: 33000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [6940]

VM Regions Near 0x8:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000104cd3000-0000000104fa4000 [ 2884K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/*/*.7

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   org.python.python               0x00000001052b4bbc PyTuple_New + 252
1   org.python.python               0x00000001052b76ba PyType_Ready + 218
2   org.python.python               0x00000001052b767c PyType_Ready + 156
3   _controller.so                  0x000000010515b227 SwigPyPacked_TypeOnce() + 87
4   _controller.so                  0x0000000105112a1f SwigPyPacked_type() + 47
5   _controller.so                  0x0000000105110b02 PyInit__controller + 34
6   python                          0x0000000104e6ca6d _PyImport_LoadDynamicModuleWithSpec + 557
7   python                          0x0000000104e6be83 _imp_create_dynamic + 243
8   python                          0x0000000104d0182f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
9   python                          0x0000000104d02f3d PyCFunction_Call + 61
10  python                          0x0000000104e3cb50 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46624
11  python                          0x0000000104e302ee _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
12  python                          0x0000000104d02623 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
13  python                          0x0000000104e3ec07 call_function + 183
14  python                          0x0000000104e3ba36 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42246
15  python                          0x0000000104d01ef5 function_code_fastcall + 117
16  python                          0x0000000104e3ec07 call_function + 183
17  python                          0x0000000104e3b9a0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42096
18  python                          0x0000000104d01ef5 function_code_fastcall + 117
19  python                          0x0000000104e3ec07 call_function + 183
20  python                          0x0000000104e3c978 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46152
21  python                          0x0000000104d01ef5 function_code_fastcall + 117
22  python                          0x0000000104e3ec07 call_function + 183
23  python                          0x0000000104e3c978 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46152
24  python                          0x0000000104d01ef5 function_code_fastcall + 117
25  python                          0x0000000104e3ec07 call_function + 183
26  python                          0x0000000104e3c978 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46152
27  python                          0x0000000104d01ef5 function_code_fastcall + 117
28  python                          0x0000000104d04598 object_vacall + 248
29  python                          0x0000000104d04793 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
30  python                          0x0000000104e655e8 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 3640
31  python                          0x0000000104e3a7be _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 37518
32  python                          0x0000000104e302ee _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
33  python                          0x0000000104e2ad1b builtin_exec + 347
34  python                          0x0000000104d0182f _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 255
35  python                          0x0000000104d02f3d PyCFunction_Call + 61
36  python                          0x0000000104e3cb50 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46624
37  python                          0x0000000104e302ee _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
38  python                          0x0000000104d02623 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 195
39  python                          0x0000000104e3ec07 call_function + 183
40  python                          0x0000000104e3ba36 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42246
41  python                          0x0000000104d01ef5 function_code_fastcall + 117
42  python                          0x0000000104e3ec07 call_function + 183
43  python                          0x0000000104e3b9a0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42096
44  python                          0x0000000104d01ef5 function_code_fastcall + 117
45  python                          0x0000000104e3ec07 call_function + 183
46  python                          0x0000000104e3c978 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46152
47  python                          0x0000000104d01ef5 function_code_fastcall + 117
48  python                          0x0000000104e3ec07 call_function + 183
49  python                          0x0000000104e3c978 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46152
50  python                          0x0000000104d01ef5 function_code_fastcall + 117
51  python                          0x0000000104d04598 object_vacall + 248
52  python                          0x0000000104d04793 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 243
53  python                          0x0000000104e655e8 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 3640
54  python                          0x0000000104e3a7be _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 37518
55  python                          0x0000000104e302ee _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 414
56  python                          0x0000000104e93b30 PyRun_FileExFlags + 256
57  python                          0x0000000104e92fa7 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 391
58  python                          0x0000000104ec0c03 pymain_main + 9635
59  python                          0x0000000104cd4b4d main + 125
60  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff605f73d5 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007ff0981d0070  rdx: 0x0000000000000001
  rdi: 0x00007ffeeaf29720  rsi: 0x00000000000000b0  rbp: 0x00007ffeeaf297b0  rsp: 0x00007ffeeaf297a0
   r8: 0x000000000004896a   r9: 0xffffffff00000000  r10: 0x00007fff965bdf20  r11: 0x0000000000007268
  r12: 0x00007ff0980fe1f0  r13: 0x00007ff0981b6cb0  r14: 0x00007ff0981d0090  r15: 0x00007ff0981b87b0
  rip: 0x00000001052b4bbc  rfl: 0x0000000000010286  cr2: 0x0000000000000008

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x104cd3000 -        0x104fa3ff3 +python (0) <2B301754-257D-3DA4-AE87-D8E7130D0FDD> /Users/USER/*/python
       0x10510b000 -        0x10510cffb +_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <D906D624-3DB4-38D7-BBA7-C5A190E6004D> /Users/USER/*/_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x105110000 -        0x105174ffb +_controller.so (0) <463868E2-5338-37BE-9ACD-C7724ED991D2> /Applications/Webots.app/lib/controller/python37/_controller.so
       0x10519b000 -        0x1051f7ff3 +libController.dylib (0) <A4DC5732-6D61-39C2-BD67-50B59BAF0811> /Applications/Webots.app/lib/controller/libController.dylib
       0x105209000 -        0x10521fff3 +libCppController.dylib (0) <9501D468-20A7-3C3D-869A-0346F0011AAB> /Applications/Webots.app/lib/controller/libCppController.dylib
       0x10524d000 -        0x105426fff +org.python.python (3.7.4, [c] 2001-2019 Python Software Foundation. - 3.7.4) <AC1AEBEB-FF5A-32AD-BAE0-C6A0BCA86B84> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
       0x10be10000 -        0x10be7a70f  dyld (655.1.1) <B3D9DDCB-5AA7-3674-9608-16B5AA4AA494> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff34636000 -     0x7fff34a7bfef  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1575.23) <596DBC2A-60E3-3A73-AA5F-7A1806CF3204> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff5d19b000 -     0x7fff5d19cffb  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (107) <A14D0819-0970-34CD-8680-80E4D7FE8C2C> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff5d5db000 -     0x7fff5d5dcffb  libSystem.B.dylib (1252.250.1) <9AA73992-2087-34AF-803E-2D727104B989> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff5d820000 -     0x7fff5d873ff7  libc++.1.dylib (400.9.4) <9A60A190-6C34-339F-BB3D-AACE942009A4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff5d874000 -     0x7fff5d889ff7  libc++abi.dylib (400.17) <38C09CED-9090-3719-90F3-04A2749F5428> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff5e2d0000 -     0x7fff5e531ffb  libicucore.A.dylib (62141.0.1) <A0D63918-76E9-3C1B-B255-46F4C1DA7FE8> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff5ee14000 -     0x7fff5f599fdf  libobjc.A.dylib (756.2) <7C312627-43CB-3234-9324-4DEA92D59F50> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff5fc84000 -     0x7fff5fc96ff7  libz.1.dylib (70.200.4) <B048FC1F-058F-3A08-A1FE-81D5308CB3E6> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff6047a000 -     0x7fff6047eff3  libcache.dylib (81) <1987D1E1-DB11-3291-B12A-EBD55848E02D> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff6047f000 -     0x7fff60489ff3  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60118.250.2) <1765BB6E-6784-3653-B16B-CB839721DC9A> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff6048a000 -     0x7fff60491ff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (63.4) <5212BA7B-B7EA-37B4-AF6E-AC4F507EDFB8> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff60492000 -     0x7fff6049bff7  libcopyfile.dylib (146.250.1) <98CD00CD-9B91-3B5C-A9DB-842638050FA8> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff6049c000 -     0x7fff60520fc3  libcorecrypto.dylib (602.260.2) <01464D24-570C-3B83-9D18-467769E0FCDD> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff605a7000 -     0x7fff605e0ff7  libdispatch.dylib (1008.270.1) <97273678-E94C-3C8C-89F6-2E2020F4B43B> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff605e1000 -     0x7fff6060dff7  libdyld.dylib (655.1.1) <002418CC-AD11-3D10-865B-015591D24E6C> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff6060e000 -     0x7fff6060effb  libkeymgr.dylib (30) <0D0F9CA2-8D5A-3273-8723-59987B5827F2> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff6061c000 -     0x7fff6061cff7  liblaunch.dylib (1336.261.2) <2B07E27E-D404-3E98-9D28-BCA641E5C479> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff6061d000 -     0x7fff60622fff  libmacho.dylib (927.0.3) <A377D608-77AB-3F6E-90F0-B4F251A5C12F> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff60623000 -     0x7fff60625ff7  libquarantine.dylib (86.270.1) <50A89DAB-7E34-3347-9AD5-68957B27EFD2> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff60626000 -     0x7fff60627ff7  libremovefile.dylib (45.200.2) <9FBEB2FF-EEBE-31BC-BCFC-C71F8D0E99B6> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff60628000 -     0x7fff6063fff3  libsystem_asl.dylib (356.200.4) <A62A7249-38B8-33FA-9875-F1852590796C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff60640000 -     0x7fff60640ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (73) <A453E8EE-860D-3CED-B5DC-BE54E9DB4348> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff60641000 -     0x7fff606c8fff  libsystem_c.dylib (1272.250.1) <7EDACF78-2FA3-35B8-B051-D70475A35117> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff606c9000 -     0x7fff606ccffb  libsystem_configuration.dylib (963.270.3) <2B4A836D-68A4-33E6-8D48-CD4486B03387> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff606cd000 -     0x7fff606d0ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (66) <719F75A4-74C5-3BA6-A09E-0C5A3E5889D7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff606d1000 -     0x7fff606d7fff  libsystem_darwin.dylib (1272.250.1) <EC9B39A5-9592-3577-8997-7DC721D20D8C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
    0x7fff606d8000 -     0x7fff606deffb  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (878.270.3) <97EEE658-D935-33C8-B56E-0F41EA7F6B43> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff606df000 -     0x7fff6072affb  libsystem_info.dylib (517.200.9) <D09D5AE0-2FDC-3A6D-93EC-729F931B1457> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff6072b000 -     0x7fff60753ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (4903.278.19) <2C2536E7-EA3B-32B5-AFC6-B1139A5046FD> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff60754000 -     0x7fff6079fff7  libsystem_m.dylib (3158.200.7) <F19B6DB7-014F-3820-831F-389CCDA06EF6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff607a0000 -     0x7fff607cafff  libsystem_malloc.dylib (166.270.1) <011F3AD0-8E6A-3A89-AE64-6E5F6840F30A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff607cb000 -     0x7fff607d5ff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (767.250.2) <FF06F13A-AEFE-3A27-A073-910EF78AEA36> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff607d6000 -     0x7fff607ddfff  libsystem_notify.dylib (172.200.21) <145B5CFC-CF73-33CE-BD3D-E8DDE268FFDE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff607de000 -     0x7fff607e7fef  libsystem_platform.dylib (177.270.1) <9D1FE5E4-EB7D-3B3F-A8D1-A96D9CF1348C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff607e8000 -     0x7fff607f2ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (330.250.2) <2D5C08FF-484F-3D59-9132-CE1DCB3F76D7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff607f3000 -     0x7fff607f6ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (851.270.1) <9494594B-5199-3186-82AB-5FF8BED6EE16> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff607f7000 -     0x7fff607f9ff3  libsystem_secinit.dylib (30.260.2) <EF1EA47B-7B22-35E8-BD9B-F7003DCB96AE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff607fa000 -     0x7fff60801ff3  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (820.267.1) <03F1C2DD-0F5A-3D9D-88F6-B26C0F94EB52> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fff60802000 -     0x7fff60817ff7  libsystem_trace.dylib (906.260.2) <EA74D04D-5ECA-3689-9084-48E4D32C859A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff60819000 -     0x7fff6081effb  libunwind.dylib (35.4) <24A97A67-F017-3CFC-B0D0-6BD0224B1336> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff6081f000 -     0x7fff6084efff  libxpc.dylib (1336.261.2) <7DEE2300-6D8E-3C00-9C63-E3E80D56B0C4> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 105089
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 33

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=248.2M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=248.2M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=427.5M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=427.5M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                            75.1M       16 
MALLOC guard page                   24K        5 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         336.0M        3         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                          4K        1 
Stack                             16.0M        1 
__DATA                            4808K       51 
__LINKEDIT                       224.3M        8 
__TEXT                            23.9M       48 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
shared memory                        8K        2 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            680.6M      137 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   344.6M      137
```

===========

**Update 3**: Issue resolved !

It's working now! Thanks for your help, David & Fabien !
After doing the above modifications and having the script still crashing, I tried running with python37 instead of python.

Even though my virtual env (anaconda) should also use 3.7 (running python --version yields the same as python3.7 --version), I found out that when running the external controller script with python3.7 works.
It seems like Webots is not playing well with virtual envs for the moment.

```
(base) mac:$ python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.4
(base) mac:$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
(base) mac:$ which python3.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
(base) mac:$ which python
/Users/[user]/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Comment: Can you please add the output you get when adding this to your controller before importing 'controller': https://gist.github.com/DavidMansolino/36bd6f8ae702d617b718e57944b9cbb7

Comment: @DavidMansolino updated the original question with the information required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webots is unfortunately quite sensitive to which Python version is used. You probably didn't installed Python as explained [here](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-python) (From the official installer).

A correct installation should lead to this result:

[image]

Please do not use Python from brew or embedded in another app (PyCharm, etc).

Comment: I can't really change the system's default python version (2.7) as you may know, other services might depend on it and, understandably, I don't want to introduce a whole new bunch of issues.
I'm using anaconda to manage python envs, and I have downgraded now: 


Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin

----
To now avail, unfortunately. (PyCharm Webots is also not working on my Mac - is it working for you ?).

Comment: Nevermind, issue is resolved (check original question for solution). Indead, virtual envs seems not to play nicely with Webots (yet).

Comment: To avoid other people running into this issue, maybe a warning/tip should be added to the docs that virtual python envs are not yet supported for webots and the usage of a system wide installed python37 command is recommended.

Comment: Indeed @Aerodynamic, could have saved me a lot of headache and time if I knew virtualenv like the ones through Anaconda does not work yet with Webots :)

Comment: In fact, it's quite easy to recompile the Webots python libraries to support any Python release. To do so, just follow these instructions: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-python#use-an-alternative-python-version Or rebuild Webots entirely from sources.

Answer (score 2):

From the output you added, it seems there is a small issue in the environment variables you set.

For the variable `PYTHONPATH`, you should change the `3X` part by your version of python. In your case, `PYTHONPATH` should point to `/Applications/Webots/lib/controller/python37`.

Comment: Thanks, oversight from me part, yet after changing to 37, it still didn't find the module. Then I changed WEBOTS_HOME="/Applications/Webots.app" (guide omits the .app). Now, although it seems to run, I'm getting the following error when I try running the script (while Webots is running, controller set to extern): Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Good, we are progressing, I will fix the missing '.app' in the guide (https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/pull/1295). Can you see in the Webots console that the controller started when you launch it?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no output in the webots console.

Comment: Not even a "INDO: Starting extern controller for robot ..." ?

Comment: Updated the question with crash report details

Comment: Thank you, I will check this.

Comment: Strangely enough, not even a "Starting extern controller for robot" appears in the console, but neither does it for the sample nao file when it's control is set to "extern" (Webots 2020 latest)